# How can I ensure my Fuse Angular Admin Template project stays current with updates from the main repository?

Tags: angular, typescript, github, frameworks, themes

I've recently acquired the [Fuse - Angular Admin Template](https://fusetheme.com/admin-templates/angular/) for a web project I'm working on. My primary concern now is how to keep my project in sync with the main GitHub repository of the template.

I've already forked their repository, which comprises five branches (demo, starter, dev-starter, dev, standalone). My plan is to start working on the starter branch immediately. Then, whenever the template's developers release updates, I intend to pull those updates into my project without affecting my existing code.

Can anyone who has experience with this template confirm if my approach is correct? Any guidance on how to effectively manage updates from the main repository would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with several projects using the Fuse for Angular template.

While the template is very rich in its components, resources and responsivity, there will be cases when you will not have a solution to what you need to implement from the template, and you'll have to code some on your own. After your project advances, you will find that your code will be a merge of Fuse components and original code.

These two aren't compatible. The code that you write that's outside of the template will have been designed specifically for that template version, and you don't have any guarantee that any future Fuse release will be compatible with your own code.

It can happen with something as simple as the update of a CSS attribute. Today your code is in perfect order, but then tomorrow the template gets updated, something gets moved around and then your view will be all over the place.

Also, the changes they apply are sometimes linked to the updates of Angular itself, so changes in more recent Fuse versions might not even compile if you attempt to have the most updated one (just as they did when they transformed the template to prioritize standalone components).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

I ended up forking their original repo and I created a new directory  in the `src` folder to make sure my project is isolated from any future updates that might be added by Fuse specifically in the `app` folder.  

I also checked most of the places that has been updated recently to make sure that I'm aware of what's getting updated frequently and what's not so that I can try to avoid conflicts as much as I can. 

I'm sure that their might be some conflicts when pulling updates, but it's ok, at least I will have less problems than updating the project my-self.